# How can I write <a> tag in standard html?

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I have two pages made using HTML and I use the following standards

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

The two pages are **index.html**, the other is **about.html**. I create a logo inside the index page as the following

HTML markup of **Index.html**

```
<div class="logo"></div>
```

in CSS I do the following

```
.logo {
background: url ('../images/logo.png') no-repeat;
height: 300px;
width: 100px;
}
```

In **about.html** page I write the following html markup

```
<a href="index.html">
   <div class="logo"></div>
</a>
```

The above markup is working fine, but when I use the **w3c validator** it gives me warning as it's not a standard markup.

My question is how can I make the html markup fits with the standards and gives the same result?

Comment: It might help if you post the warning that the validator gives you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do this rather:

```
<a href="index.html" class="logo"></a>
```

And then your css will apply directly to the `a` instead of to a nested empty `div`. You'll need to add `display: block;` to the CSS though because `a` has a different default `display`.

Comment: thanks a lot ! it really works, you are really great with a great help . thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have two choices if you need to keep this markup structure:

1. Use the HTML5 doctype, where block level elements inside anchors like `<a><div>this</div></a>` are valid and legal.

   The HTML5 doctype is: `<!doctype html>`

   Just bear in mind that there is currently no official HTML5 validation service.
2. Use an inline element like `<span>` for the logo:

   ```
   <a href="index.html">
      <span class="logo"></span>
   </a>
   ```

If you use #2, just add `display:block` to your CSS for `.logo`

Depending on your design goals and other markup, you may very well not need the inner element at all and can simply style the `<a>` element itself by giving it `class="logo"`.

Comment: +1 for `display:block`. You don't even need the span element, the style can directly be applied on `<a>`.

Comment: No you don't *need* it, but I'm not sure what else the OP is up to with the design. Could be a "helper" tag or something, or maybe there are other adjacent elements in the `<a>`. There are too many ways to possibly mark this up, just going with the OP's original HTML.

Comment: @Madmartigan thanks a lot, but i need that standard - html section 4 - as client ask for that specifically.

Comment: Then you'll have to use an inline element like `<span>`, no inner element at all, or accept that the document doesn't validate.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're seeing in the validator is because the `<div>` is a block-level tag, whereas the `<a>` tag is an inline tag.

Inline tags cannot contain block-level tags, which is why the validator is complaining.

In fact, this rule is widely ignored, because otherwise a lot of things become quite hard to make into links. In addition, it only applies to older HTML and xhtml versions (xhtml is particularly fussy about it); the current HTML5 standard does allow it, because they saw the problems caused by having the rule.

So the short answer is to use the HTML doctype (`<!DOCTYPE HTML>`)instead, and your problem will disappear.

The 'correct' answer is to style the `<a>` tag with `display:block;` or `display:inline-block;` so that it can then contain block-level elements. This will make it correct syntactically. However this doesn't usually satisfy the validator, as it just looks at the default display types, not CSS.

Alternatively, switch the `<div>` for a `<span>`. This will satisfy the validator, and you can still use `display:block` and friends to make it work like a `<div>`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks a lot, but i need that standard - html section 4 - as client ask for that specifically.

Comment: @HTMLMan - in that case, the last paragraph of my answer provides the solution: switch to `<span>` rather than `<div>` inside an `<a>` tag. It's the only way to satisfy the HTML4 rules fully.

Comment: "In fact, this rule is widely ignored, because otherwise a lot of things become quite hard to make into links." What would be an example of this, where you couldn't place the link inside the block?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the logo image as a background put an  tag inside your DIV. You cannot wrap an  tag around a block element like a DIV.

```
<a href="index.html">
   <div class="logo">
      <a href='gosomewhere.html'>
         <img src='mylogo.png'alt='' title=''/>
      </a>
   </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I know that, but imagine i have 20 pages using html and your code a little bit long and a little bit noise when you read it from another one else

Comment: Agreed, wasnt sure if you wanted to keep the DIV structure. Also adding the image via the CSS you lose the ability to add TITLE and ALT tags which can be important for SEO and Accessibility, for instance images of products your selling, etc.. I guess it all depends on what the images are.

Comment: yes you are totally right, but i use that only for logo, i think no problem at all if no one with disability cannot read the logo or my page have a broken link for logo.

Comment: also i can use title with <a> tag

Comment: Correct, but search engines will look at that differently than an <img> tag with a TITLE and ALT tag. For your need, applying the image via a CSS class is the way to go for a logo, but if you were listing products or other things you would want indexed by the Search Engines then its much better semantics to use an <img> tag with a TITLE and ALT tag.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, and i will keep that in my mind. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Links (`a` tags) are inline elements, meaning multiple elements fit on the same line, while `div`s are block elements, which mean only one per line. It is invalid HTML 4.01 to insert a block-style element inside an inline-style element, since that prevents the inline element from actually being rendered as inline.

For more info on inline and block elements, see this page: http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-css/css-block-and-inline/

Answer (score 0):

No it not valid to put and `Div` tag inside an `Anchor` Tag According to section 4 of W3c standards.
An `anchor` tag is an `iline` element and `Div` is a `block` level element. You cannot put a `block` level element inside and `inline` element.

Here is another good SO discussion on your matter.
[Is putting a div inside an anchor ever correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827965/is-putting-a-div-inside-a-anchor-ever-correct)